# Dynamically rename columns in Python / Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

New to Pandas, but I'm diving right into the nitty-gritty:

I have CSV files that I'm reading into Pandas data frame (before importing them into a SQL db). The columns look like this:

```
ID    QUESTION_1_SOME_RANDOM_STRING
1     answer to Q1
```

Now I have lots of different files, and while they are otherwise identical in structure, the string at the end of the name of the second column is something unknown (it's different in all the files).

How can I dynamically rename the second column from "QUESTION_1_SOME_RANDOM_STRING" to "QUESTION_1" - without knowing what the string is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex to match "QUESTION_n":

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(QUESTION_\d+).*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

or [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)+[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.columns = ((s:=df.columns.to_series())
              .str.extract(r'(QUESTION_\d+)', expand=False)
              .fillna(s)
             )
```

Output:

```
   ID    QUESTION_1
0   1  answer to Q1
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! However, it turns out that I was thinking too complicated and the hint @BigBen gave in the comment might, in fact, lead to the easiest solution EDIT: which he now has removed again. I will post as an answer.

Comment: @Sebastian it depends if the positions are fixed in the CSV, if yes, then just pass names

Comment: indeed. Though the general applicability of your answer is why this is the "correct" answer to my question - thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer @mozway gave above is correct and generally applicable, there is in fact an easier answer - if (and only if) the positions of the columns within the CSV are fixed. If that is the case, the easiest solution is to simply hard-code the column names while reading the CSV, like so:

```
colnames=[ID, QUESTION_1]

pd.read_csv(f'{filename}', delimiter=';',names=colnames, header=0)
```